# author.php get current id of author for advance custom field

Tags: author, author-template

I'm not sure why there is no result with advance custom fields. i use `get_the_author_meta('ID')` for other information since it's work with single.php but i want also to display the information of author / grantor in author or profile page but no result. Any idea please check my code below.

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="infomation-section">
          <?php $user_id = get_the_author_meta('ID'); ?>
        <h3 class="info-title">Grantor Informations</h3>
        <div class="info-grantor-info">
        <div class="info-image">
            <?php echo get_avatar(get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ), 100); ?>
        </div>
            <h3 class="info-name"><?php the_field('grantor_name', 'user_'.$user_id);?></h3>
            <p class="info-address">
                <?php the_field('full_address', 'user_'.$user_id);?>
            </p>
        </div>
        <?php if (get_field('telephone_number', 'user_'.$user_id)) : ?>
        <div class="info-number">
            <h4>Telephone Number:</h4>
            <p><?php the_field('telephone_number', 'user_'.$user_id);?></p>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if (get_field('fax_number', 'user_'.$user_id)) : ?>
        <div class="info-number">
            <h4>Fax Number :</h4>
            <p><?php the_field('fax_number', 'user_'.$user_id);?></p>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if (get_field('email_address', 'user_'.$user_id)) : ?>
        <div class="info-email">
            <h4>Email Address :</h4>
            <p><?php the_field('email_address', 'user_'.$user_id);?></p>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="program-section">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve this problem by using this code

`<?php $curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author)); ?>`

`<?php the_field('grantor_name', 'user_'.$curauth->ID)`